# Android, Kotlin: declaring an interface like "public @interface"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, interface, annotations

I've not found a single mention of this subject neither on SO, nor elsewhere. And I am really curious about this one.
*Note: I am using Kotlin in my android project.*

In the **androidx.room** there is a **Dao.java** file with such content:

```
package androidx.room;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * Marks the class as a Data Access Object.
 * <p>
 * Data Access Objects are the main classes where you define your database interactions. They can
 * include a variety of query methods.
 * <p>
 * The class marked with {@code @Dao} should either be an interface or an abstract class. At compile
 * time, Room will generate an implementation of this class when it is referenced by a
 * {@link Database}.
 * <p>
 * An abstract {@code @Dao} class can optionally have a constructor that takes a {@link Database}
 * as its only parameter.
 * <p>
 * It is recommended to have multiple {@code Dao} classes in your codebase depending on the tables
 * they touch.
 *
 * @see Query
 * @see Delete
 * @see Insert
 */
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface Dao {
}
```

I am confused about the `public @interface Dao {}` as it looks as if it could be just `public interface Dao{}`. But there is an `"@"` before the `"interface"` keyword.

Creating my own interface in kotlin with this syntax produces a compilation error `"expected annotation identifier after '@'"` (example right below)

```
public @interface TestInterface {
    
}
```

Is this an equivalent of "annotation class" or something else?

Why is it allowed in Dao.java and what are its functions?

Comment: You should read about annotations - Java or Kotlin, as they mostly have same uses. You will probably find more info for Java. This is a rather long story and explaining it would be pretty much copying the official documentation.

Comment: Also, Java is not Kotlin, so Java syntax will not necessarily work in a Kotlin source file.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#accessing-properties-of-an-annotation-instance

Comment: Right, I haven't thought about it that way. It seems like it is a standard annotation interface declaration in Java. I have not used java for quite a long time. Thanks for the hints. I mean I've never used custom annotation interfaces in Java.

Comment: Yes, this is how annotations are defined in Java. Nothing special about this specific annotation.